# Apache2 Alias working locally but not working for sub directory on another server

Tags: php, apache

I have the same configuration and set up only the versions of Apache2 are slightly different. I have set up `/api` to load the `/public`.

So, locally (apache 2.4.18)

`mysite.local` correctly loads `/var/www/mysite/application`

`mysite.local/api` correctly loads `/var/www/mysite/public`

`mysite.local/api/subdirectory` correctly loads `/var/www/mysite/public`

I want to replicate this on a hosted dev server (Apache 2.4.7) however I am getting the following:

`mysite.devserver.com` correctly loads `/var/www/html/mysite/application`
`mysite.devserver.com/api` correctly loads `/var/www/html/mysite/public`
`mysite.devserver.com/api/subdirectory` **incorrectly** loads `/var/www/html/mysite/application`

Local `mysite.conf` file (working)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mysite.local
        ServerAlias www.mysite.local
        Alias /api /var/www/mysite/public
        <Directory /var/www/mysite/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/application
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Dev server conf file (not working)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName mysite.devserver.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        Alias /api /var/www/html/mysite/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/mysite>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/application
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried to add the Alias into `mods-enabled` but its not making a difference. The code is the exact same, same .htaccess files in both instances.

Comment: I just tried v2.4.28, it works properly.  At this point, you should consider upgrading your dev server (if you can!).